# IndexOf different results with input with spaces

Tags: java, string

I'm facing a little problem when getting all the strings between two delimiters.
As I saw on other related questions, (one of) the way to get characters between two delimiters is as follow:
Given some string, in my example here `"void foo(int a, int b) {"`, I want to get every char between the parentheses.
Using:

```
String parameters = currLine.trim().substring(currLine.indexOf("("),
                    currLine.indexOf(")")-1);
```

Where `currLine` is of course `"void foo(int a, int b) {"`.
Now everything works perfectly, since I get the `"int a, int b"` strings.
The problem is that with a string like the following:

```
    void                    foo                   (    int a      ,      String      b              )               {
```

I get that:
parameters = `"nt a      ,      String       b              )    "`
And I have no idea how to fix this without causing it problems to the first case.

Comment: You've trimmed the text but you've calculated the index of the parentheses in the untrimmed text, so your indexes are wrong. Probably better to simply trim the result at the end, and don't trim beforehand.

Comment: Simplest thing is to skip calling `trim()` in this scenario since you are only interested in what’s inside the parentheses

Comment: String is immutable. `trim()` method doesn't modify original string, but creates new one (so `currLine` still holds original non-trimmed string and indexes you receive are also based on it). Also I am not sure what you are trying to achieve using `trim()` here. Consider clarifying its purpose in the question.

Comment: While you're playing with string parsing you might want to check regular expressions. Once you get it you can't love without it!

Comment: If I understood correctly, since String is immutable, trim creates a copy instead of modifying the original string. But shouldn't the substring method operates on this newly created trimmed String copy instead of the original currLine ? Shouldn't currLine.trim() return the new copy ?

Comment: Yes @MM1, but the problem appears when you compute `indexOf`, you perform that operation over the original `String` not the trimmed one.

Comment: Ah yes I see, so I should have done something like currLine.trim().indexOf (or just calling trim() at the end as stated in previous comments).

Comment: You could use ``parameters = parameters.replaceAll("\\s\\s+", " ");`` Replace every group of spaces > 1 with just a single space.

Comment: Yes, that is right @MM1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `trim` does not modify the original `String`. As a consequence, when you calculate the `substring` you obtain different results depending on whether the input `String` has or not white spaces at the beginning or end, because `indexOf` is operating on the original `String`.

One possible solution could be the following:

```java
// Trim the value
String trimmed = currLine.trim();
// And operate with it
String parameters = trimmed.substring(trimmed.indexOf("("),
                    trimmed.indexOf(")")-1);
```

A possible better approach would be to compute a regex over the provided value to extract the information between parenthesis, something like:

```java
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(currLine);
if (m.find()) {
  String parameters = m.group(1);
  // Operate with parameters
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be as follows:

```
String parameters = currLine.substring(currLine.indexOf("(") + 1, currLine.indexOf(")")).trim();
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String currLine = "void                    foo                   (    int a      ,      String      b              )               {                 ";
        String parameters = currLine.substring(currLine.indexOf("(") + 1, currLine.indexOf(")")).trim();
        System.out.println(parameters);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
int a      ,      String      b
```

Note that [`String#substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) returns the substring beginning at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`.